# How to use crefvim?

Tags: vim

This is a rather noob question. Here it goes.
I'm trying to get CRefVim to work. I find the plugin description pretty useful.

My problem is... I just don't understand how to get it working.

For example if I want to lookup 'malloc'...

By doing 'scriptnames' command, I can see the plugin is running.

The doc says

```
  <Leader>cr normal mode:  get help for word under cursor 
                           Memory aid cr: (c)-(r)eference 
  <Leader>cr visual mode:  get help for visually selected text 
                           Memory aid cr: (c)-(r)eference 
  <Leader>cw:              prompt for word CRefVim should search for 
                           Memory aid cw: (c)-reference (w)hat 
  <Leader>cc:              jump to table of contents of the C-reference manual 
                           Memory aid cc: (c)-reference (c)ontents
```

First, I did not know what was leader, so I searched.
It seems it is a key. I set it to "#" with let mapleader="#", which corresponds to the key under my ESC key.
Then what?
I'm supposed to do the key "c" + "r"? It just... doesn't work..

Help me please
Thanks

EDIT: Using gvim 7.4 under windows 7 by the way

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question if you defined your custom `<leader>` manually on the command-line or in your `$HOME\_vimrc`.

Issuing `let mapleader = "#"` after your `$HOME\_vimrc` and plugins are read *won't change existing `<leader>` mappings*: only mappings defined *after* you changed your `<leader>` key will use that new `<leader>`.

If `let mapleader = "#"` is in your `$HOME\_vimrc` and is not overwritten somewhere else, typing `#cr` in normal or visual mode should just work.

If it doesn't, try `:verbose map <leader>` to see if the plugin actually registered those mappings and with what `<leader>` key.

Comment: Indeed, my mistake. I was defining the leader key after _vimrc initialization. I guess the command 'let mapleader=key' takes it's sense only when it's on top of _vimrc. I've read somewhere Vim actually substitutes it in expressions. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By default `<leader>` is the backslash key.

To get help for `malloc` place the cursor over `malloc` and press the key sequence `\cr` in normal mode. Crefvim should then jump to the section that describes `malloc`.